# Why is my sticky-top navbar showing half the navbar until I scroll down further?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I downloaded the following free-css template:

https://themewagon.github.io/kider/

I am attempting to replace the icon in the navigational bar with my own custom logo. So rather than this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top px-4 px-lg-5 py-lg-0">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-primary"><i class="fa fa-book-reader me-3"></i>Kider</h1>
        </a>
        ...
        ...
        ...
</nav>
```

[image: Default Picture]

I am attempting to do this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top px-4 px-lg-5 py-lg-0">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-primary"><img src="img/logo.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: auto;">My School Name</h1>
        </a>
        ...
        ...
        ...
</nav>
```

[image: Attempted Picture]

Noticeably, the vertical height of the navbar has slightly more than doubled. The issue I am getting comes when I scroll down. With the default icon, as you scroll down slowly, the navbar disappears entirely from view. Scroll down just a bit further, and the navbar will then sticky to the top of the page.

With the new image, rather than disappearing entirely as I scroll down, half of the navigational bar shows:

[image: Faulty Navbar]

Once I scroll a bit further, the full navbar sticks to the top of the screen like I want. It seems that the amount that my navbar is sticking out while I scroll down is the difference in vertical size between the original icon and the new image.

For the life of me, I cannot seem to figure where I need to go to make this work the way I want. I have tried the following:

- In styles.css, change this line of code:

  .navbar.sticky-top {
  top: -100px;
  transition: .5s;
  }

Unfortunately, the top setting just gets overwritten.

- Searched bootstrap.min.css, and changed all the top settings for the sticky class.
- Adding class="align-middle" to the nav tag.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you eliminate the star image as a factor?

Comment: In any case, if your new header is taller and the original translation movement is in pixels, obviously you need to adjust the value to match what your new header height is. From a high-level I question why hard pixel values are used, but that could be for reasons of smoother animation. Your CSS trial may not work because something is overriding it, either other CSS using `!important` or maybe there's some dynamic JS involved.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The star image is definitely the factor; if I change the size to be roughly the same as the icon it is replacing, the translation movement works without issues. I definitely think something is overriding, I just don't understand why. Using developer tools, I see that the top property of .navbar.sticky-top is being overridden.

Comment: If I were you, I would abandon the template's drop-down menu, and make your own using a modern tutorial. That way you have complete control and know exactly what's going on.